# Executing Java from CGI (Java cannot find or load the main class)

Tags: java, apache, cgi

I have a weird problem running cgi's from Apache. I have the following cgi:

```
 #!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
use File::Basename;
use Cwd 'chdir';

$DIR=dirname($0);
chdir $DIR;

print "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";
#print $DIR;
$Result = `java -classpath . CONCATARR`;
print $result;
```

This cgi is working fine from the command line, but not from the browser. From the browser java is throwing the following error: Error: Could not find or load main class CONCATARR

The file CONCATARR.class is, of course, in the cgi folder. When I printed the dir, it is pointing the cgi folder too.

That is the problem, to test it in a different way I did also a php file:

```
<html> <head> <title>Test</title> </head>

<body> <?
chdir('C:/xampp/cgi-bin');
$output = shell_exec("java -classpath . CONCATARR");
echo $output;
?> </body> </html>
```

which has the same problem, is running fine from the command line but not from the browser (same error).

The cgi-bin folder has been configured as suggested in the manual (in fact, the cgi is executed, java is failing...), all the files and folders inside cgi-bin have the permissions to be read and executed, Apache service is allowed to interact with desktop.

I have been trying to make it work for two days and checked tens of forums, so probably I have tried more things that I do not remember now...

Any help is very welcome.

Configuration: Windows Server 2008 R2, xammp. (If some more details are needed to find out a solution please ask)

**Edit in response to the first answer:**

Thanks for the answer, about those three things, I think I have cover them:

1: the name is right and the file is there, all with caps.

2: The .class has a main method, in fact is was used before in an iOS system. The .java correspondent to that class is starting like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
class CONCATARR
{
public  static  void  main( String  args[] ) throws Exception
{
System.out.print("Content-type: text/xml\n");
System.out.print("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\n\n");
```

3: this is the httpd.conf file (the part regarding the cgi directory

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>
<IfModule cgid_module>
</IfModule>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The file and the folder have all the permissions to read and execute for all the users...

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Out of curiosity - does it work when you do `$Result = 'java -cp ' . $DIR . '  CONCATARR'`?

Comment: In that case the error is: Error: Could not find or load main class . instead of Error: Could not find or load main class CONCATARR

Comment: (I'm not a perl expert - I may got the string concatenation plain wrong - maybe it goes like this: `"java -cp ${DIR} CONCATARR"`)

Comment: With that, the execution command that you send is `java -cp C:/xampp/cgi-bin CONCATARR` which it should work (I think). But again the same error: Could not find or load main class CONCATARR

Comment: Just for testing: What happens when you put the `java` call into a shell script and execute this in your Perl script?

Comment: Calling the shell script from Perl is throwing the same error: Error: Could not find or load main class CONCATARR

Answer (score 0):

It should work... [This (old) tutorial](http://www.eli.sdsu.edu/courses/spring97/cs596/notes/cgiJava/cgiJava.html) shows, that the general approach is correct.

Your scripts are being executed, a JVM is started, just that it can't find or load the classfile.

Some reasons that come to my mind

- the `cgi-bin` folder has to contain a file named `CONCATARR.class` (exact spelling)
- `CONCATARR.class` needs to have a valid `main` method
- apache needs read access privileges for the `cgi-bin` folder and the class file

You may try to execute `java -version` (just to verify, that the correct java is started) and to add the `-verbose` option to get more output.

Comment: Sorry, as I am new here I cannot post a proper answer for 8h after I post my question... I will do it in 4h. Thanks

Comment: No, still the same. I just want to send you what I have done about those three points.. In 1h I will :)

Comment: You should be able to edit your question and some additional information. That's better than using an answer for that :)

Comment: Did you see my answer? Is it giving you any clue or just making more confusion :)